# Read Multi integer from user and do some iteration and calculation

Tags: c

instructions are:
 Write a program which reads 10 different integers from the user and finds and prints
a) Minimum element
b) Sum of all elements and
c) Average of elements.
Note: do not use arrays to store the user-entered integers.

i did b and c part like this but i can't a
there is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main() {
    int n, i, sum = 0;
    double avarage = 0;
    int min = 0;
    i = 1;
    while (i <= 10) {
        printf("Enter an integer: ");
        scanf ("%d", &n);
        sum += n;
        if (n < min) {
            min = n;
        }
        ++i;
    }

    printf("Sum = %d \n", sum);
    avarage = sum / 10;
    printf("Avg = %.2lf \n", avarage);
    printf("Min = %d \n", min);
}
```

this is output of my code:

[image]

How can i print Minimum of those.

Comment: Hint: what is the value of `min` when you first start checking it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you `min` variable starts with 0, so every number you entered is larger then that.

```c
int min = INT_MAX;
```

start `min` with the largest possible integer will guarantee every number you take as input will be smaller

another approach is the use a flag (like boolean) for the first input, and if so directly put it into `min`:

```c
int min = 0;
i = 1;
int my_flag=0;
while (i <= 10) {
    printf("Enter an integer: ");
    scanf ("%d", &n);
    sum += n;
    if (n < min) {
       min = n;
    }
    if(my_flag==0){
        min=n;
        my_flag=1;
    }
    ++i;
}
```

Comment: You need to give ```min``` some high value. If you assume all your inputs are smaller then x (let's say 100) then initialize ```int min=100``. It must have some initial value, and 0 is a poor choice

Comment: @dxiv I accidentally put ```min=0;``` instead of ```min=n;```. Changed it, thanks